GDB command history subset in CGDB?
When using CGDB, I typically step-debug through a program in "CGDB mode" using keyboard shortcuts; such as for the GDB's next, step, finish and continue commands.
If I then change to "GDB mode", I might want to use a command that I typed in recently, and I can use the UP arrow key to traverse previous commands; much as at the system command prompt. For example p this->foo_->get_something().xyz(). While traversing these previous commands, I find that all of the keyboard shortcuts that have been used in "CGDB mode" have also been recorded in this command history, and so I must go through all of these to get to my last typed GDB command; so I get lots of next, next, step etc.
Is there any way to configure CGDB so that it does not add commands entered in "CGDB mode" to this history buffer?

i imagine you'll need to set/reset history file,
show history
expansion:  History expansion on command input is off.
filename:  The filename in which to record the command history is "/home/ticktalkies/.gdb_history".
remove-duplicates:  The number of history entries to look back at for duplicates is 0.
save:  Saving of the history record on exit is off.
size:  The size of the command history is 256.

You are referring to the options for GDB Command History, but these can't be used to solve the problem.

i could find nothing in the documentation alluding to where cgdb stores history or to configure it as such. If the commands are in the same history as the gdb history ... then that's where they're stored. you can contact the dev team - check out https://cgdb.github.io/ for contact info
